# Trying to delete tables from active ppt slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to delete tables from the active slide in a ppt presentation, but I can only get it to work if I specify the number for the slide. I want this to work for whatever slide is active, not a specific slide. The below code is set to delete tables from slide 3.

```
Sub CopytoPPT()

    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim sl As PowerPoint.Slide, sl_cnt As Long, pr As Object, pr_name As String, ppt As Object
        Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Set ppt = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
        Set pr = ppt.Presentations(1)

    Set sl = pr.Slides(3)
    For i = sl.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    ' ADD THIS TEST
    If IsTable(sl.Shapes(i)) Then
      sl.Shapes(i).Delete
    End If
    Next i
    End Sub
    
    Function IsTable(oSh As Variant) As Boolean
        
        If oSh.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
            If oSh.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoTable Then
                IsTable = True
            End If
        Else
            If oSh.HasTable Then
                IsTable = True
            End If
            End If
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
Set sl = pr.Slides(3)
```

To:

```
Set sl = ppt.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
```

Comment: Also trying to paste in the replacement table and finding a similar problem. Copying a range from excel using (set rng = Selection; rng.copy, but can't find the right code to paste that selection on the same slide as where we deleted the previous table. any advice?